# NGSW - Re-fetch previously missing resources upon navigation

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-service-worker

I'm currently working on an Angular-PWA and am struggling with a Service-Worker/Caching issue.

Basically, we're using the Service Worker to cache the majority of app files upfront on first load. We are then using lazy-loading to retrieve other icons and images when navigating to a page that requires them.

So far everything seemed to be fine, except when I began testing its offline capabilities. When checking 'Offline' in DevTools, most of the app is still served and can be used and navigated etc, except for the missing icons and images that cannot now be retrieved. This is fine, as we're lazy-loading, it's expected behaviour.

But, after un-checking 'Offline' and re-connecting again, if I load a page  that I hadn't viewed while offline, it's resources are retrieved as normal. Yet, if I then return to a page that I did previously view while offline, it does not retrieve its missing resources and maintains its bare-bones-media-less version.

Is there a way of storing instances or references to the 'Loading chunk # failed' errors, and when a Navigation event occurs to a page where an error was thrown, maybe just display a dialog and force a location.reload(true)?

If there's anyway to do this in an Angular friendly way, do they provide any functionality to hook onto 'Loading chunk # failed' errors, and be able to store information from it?

What I think I'm after is, a way of storing error information from the Service Worker, then on Navigation events, check that information to see if it refers to the page I'm about to load, if so, load from server, if not, from cache.

So a network-then-cache policy if there are errors, normal cache policy otherwise.

Concept question, shouldn't think any of my code is required, if it is just say, any help is very much appreciated :)

Thanks guys!